# Trying to set root to devise/sessions#new results in routes mapping error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

Going demented with an issue here :-(

My requirement is as follows,

1. If a user visits myapp.com the root of my app is defaulted to promotional pages & sign-up form. This is achieved by checking for the presence of a subdomain.
2. If the user is not logged in and tries to visit their account at test.myapp.com they will be directed to test.myapp.com/users/sign_in -aka- devise/sessions#new
3. If the user is logged in (devise) and visits test.myapp.com the root of the application will be the application dashboard.

Here is what I am trying to use in my routes.rb

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  authenticated do
    root :to => 'dashboard#index'
  end
  root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
root :to => 'promo_pages#index'
```

Currently I have the following, you will note that the devise bit is not included.

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  authenticated do
    root :to => 'dashboard#index'
  end
end
root :to => 'promo_pages#index'
```

My problem with the latter is that when a user who is not logged in first visits test.myapp.com they are redirected to test.myapp.com/users/sign_in and an error message is displayed saying "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." This is because I am enforcing a logon requirement for the dashboard pages.

However I don't want the user to get an error message the first time they visit the page, as it is ugly and makes it look like they have done something wrong when they have not.

My expectation is that if the user is not logged in then they will be directed straight to the logon page and not get an error notification. But when I use my amended version the following happens,
I can visit myapp.com just fine and it is routed to the promo pages
but if I try to visit test.myapp.com I get the following message in the browser

```
**Unknown action**
Could not find devise mapping for path "/". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong (if anything) as I am going crackers trying to understand what to do.

Ps: I have found similar errors in stackoverflow and various googling but the solutions just don't seem to work for me. I expect that the solution to the problem lies in the error message that I have included above, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Finally here is the log entry version of the error above, it is in an easier to read form.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-15 21:44:42 +0000
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
[Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/".
Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

    devise_scope :user do
      match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
    end
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (Could not find devise mapping for path "/".
Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

    devise_scope :user do
      match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
    end
):
```

All help is appreciated, and additional details can be provided.

Thanks for reading

---

**Update**

I have just noticed that the 'authenticated' check does not appear to be working.
If it was working correctly then when using the second batch of working config, the logged in user visiting test.myapp.com would always be directed to the promo_pages, whereas at the moment he is able to access the dashboard..

I found the devise 'authenticated' method here
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1147

Comment: This is now resolved, but I am not allowed post the answer for another 4hrs so I will do it when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it sorted,

Ok, firstly the reason I was getting the devise error was that I needed to place the devise root statement inside the "devise_for :users" block

Secondly,
The authenticated check was not working because I failed to include a scope as I was under the mistaken impression it was not necessary.

Here is the finalised code, note that in rails routing the priority is based on order of creation, first created is highest priority. Thus in this case the promo_pages controller is only considered root if nothing else was previously specified.

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'dashboard#index'
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
end
root :to => 'promo_pages#index'
```

Answer (score 3):

Without the constraint, this will cause a Could not find devise mapping for path "/" error. This simple addition fixed it.

```
devise_scope :user do 
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'dashboard#index'
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
    end
    root :to => 'dashboard#index'
end
```